# Linear independence in 3D vector space using 2 vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

According to [this](https://youtu.be/k7RM-ot2NWY) video, two vectors can't define more than one plane (from around 5:58 to 7:23), and it takes three vectors to go beyond that one plane.

Wouldn't two vectors be enough to define the span of all vectors in 3D space? Why would we need three?

Comment: Can you construct $[0,0,1]$ using $[1,0,0]$ and $[0,1,0]$?

Comment: No, not with [1, 0, 0] and [0, 1, 0], but it *is* possible with a combination of some other two vectors, right? As in, you can define any vector in 3D space with *some* two vectors, whatever they may be?

Comment: If you choose any 2 vectors, there will still be some that you can't span, for example, take their cross product. For it to span, you need to fix the 2 vectors, and it can reach all the vectors.

Comment: @HarryHolmes, By that logic, you can get to any one vector with the span of a single vector: itself. But here we are asking what are all the vectors we can reach once we *fix* two vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine two vectors(neither one a scalar multiple of the other) that start at the origin and end at two different points of the form $(x,y,z)$
For the first vector, no matter what scalar we chose to multiply by, we will always exist on a line. If we want to leave this line we need to add a new vector. Now, no matter what scalar we multiply the second vector by we can never leave the plane...

so to leave the plane we need to add third vector(such that all three vectors are linearly independent) to the other two vectors.

Think about it like this... Can you encapsulate the full meaning of a cube on with a graph on the x,y plane?

Comment: Oh, is it like; the span is only the collection of those vectors we can obtain by scalar multiplication and vector addition, so it remains on that plane?

Comment: the span of a set of vectors is the set of all linear combinations of that set of vectors, and a linear combination, like you just said, is obtained by scalar multiplication and vector addition